# Nadal vs Federer

Tags: pattern, enigmatic-puzzle, story

**R**ecently, while traveling via air, I have been having some weird dreams. The dreams start with a tennis match between the two legends Rafael Nadal and Roger Federer taking place in the country to which I am traveling. One of them just tosses up the ball, and the dreams end with the match result.

Oh, one more thing, the tournament is named something like

**"CLOSEST FlIGHT"**.

Following are some of the results from the the recent dreams -

> Nadal vs Federer (GERMANY, Nadal Wins)
>   Nadal vs Federer (BRAZIL, Federer Wins)
>   Nadal vs Federer (INDIA, Federer Wins)
>   Nadal vs Federer (ITALY, Nadal Wins)
>   Nadal vs Federer (AUSTRALIA, Federer Wins)
>   Nadal vs Federer (USA, Federer Wins)
>   Nadal vs Federer (UK, Nadal Wins)
>   Nadal vs Federer (UKRAINE, Federer Wins)
>   Nadal vs Federer (NEW ZEALAND, Nadal Wins)
>   Nadal vs Federer (SRI LANKA, Federer Wins)
>   Nadal vs Federer (KENYA, Nadal Wins)

I will be traveling to France next week, can you help me finding who will win?

Hint

> Case matters(Already found by @Sid), also the highlighted things matters once you break the Enigma behind tournament name. Also, what's enigmatic with FLIGHT? You may utilize a little knowledge.

Comment: Would the result have been different had ROME been ITALY?

Comment: Does France mean they will compete at the French Open? In that case I'd know the answer :p

Comment: @Sconibulus Nice catch. :) It should have been ITALY at first place. But ROME works fine as well. :) But again, for the sake of pattern let me correct it.

Comment: @Levieux agreed. :P

Comment: @Levieux I am not sure if they will be facing each other there :)

Comment: "F**II**GHT" (two **I**s) on purpose?

Comment: @humn Yes. They are intentional.

Comment: @humn the first one is a lower case L

Comment: But which one of them is going to play against the blancmange?

Comment: Are you sure Federer wins UKRAINE?

Comment: @dlsso Yeah. He does. As far as I can remember :)

Comment: you sure about UKRAINE, UK and SRI LANKA?

Comment: Yeah. I'm sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay:

> The Capital letters of the countries suggests taking the Capitals. So, taking the capitals and comparing the letters to the Nadal and Federer, we notice that, whenever there is a matching letter between the name of the player and Capital's name, the player loses. But, this gives a dead end with many countries.

With some great hinting by the OP at The Sphinx Lair,

> Flight refers to Airplanes and since capital cities are mentioned, we look at the airports. I checked the IATA codes of all the main international airports of the capitals of the given countries. And the bold R in the first word of the puzzle signifies that we look at the first letters. From there, we notice, that Federer wins with codes having initial letters B,D,C,I,etc. Nadal wins with codes having initial letters T,F,Y,etc.

Why does this happen?

> As the tournament name suggest's compare the **Closest** so, if we compare the first letter of main IATA's with N/F(Nadal/Federer), which ever is closest - wins.
>  Berlin(TXL) -> T is closest to N -> Nadal Wins
>  Brasilia(BSB) -> B is closest to F -> Federer Wins
>  Delhi(ICAO) -> I is closest to to F -> Federer Wins
>  Nairobi(NBO) -> N is closest to N -> Nadal Wins

Now, the solving part:

> The main international airport at Paris, France is the [Charles De Gaulle Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_de_Gaulle_Airport). It's code=CDG. It starts with C. C is closest to F. So, there is our answer.
>  **Roger Federer wins at Paris against Rafael Nadal. (What?)**(Maybe miracles do happen, after all)

Comment: You got some more clues correct. So, summing up with F1Krazy's You all have Surnames, Letters, Capitals.. Now, its time to focus on flight. Think, what does flight stands for and what's enigmatic? There have been many similar puzzles.

Comment: @Techidiot I have compared flight distances and all. No pattern, do I see. Or is there something else?

Comment: Yes. It's something else. There is no geography tag. It's not that difficult.

Comment: I am accepting this with a note. There was an error on my end for creating the puzzle with partial knowledge of how IATA's work. My assumption was a single city has all airports with same IATA codes as I googled *IATA for Berlin* *IATA for Delhi* etc to get the codes and nothing else. Compared the first letter of that IATA with N/F(Nadal and Federer) to chose the winner. I apologize for the error and will take care of that the next time I use IATA. Thanks for participating and solving :) Cheers! +15

Answer (score 3):

My first attempt:

> You look at each letter of the tournament location in turn. When you reach a letter that occurs in one of the players' surnames, that player loses. For example, in GERMANY, the second letter `E` occurs in Federer's surname, so he loses and Nadal wins.

This works for the first six tournaments and KENYA (and also works if you replace ITALY with ROME, as you did initially) but completely falls apart for the other four. It also wouldn't work if

> the first matching letter was D, for example if a tournament was held in DUBAI.

I have a feeling I'm on the right track, though.

Comment: You are on track with a few things like - Surnames, Matching Letters etc. Bring in the tournament name in the picture and check what's enigmatic with that?